# How can I check the built-in function implementation in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to check a built-in function implementation in Xcode IDE. I mean - is there something like CTRL + [click on function name] in IntelliJ? I need to check `arc4random()` implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode, you can hold `command` + click on function name to jump to file which function is defined (.h file).

If it's a built-in function, you can only see in `.h file` (Header file). You can't open built-in function in `.m` or `.ccp` file.

With `arc4random()` you can open `stdlib.h` but you can't check how it's implemented from XCode. Luckily you can check it here https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c.

[opensource.apple.com](http://opensource.apple.com) is provided by Apple

**EDIT:**

To open `stdlib.h` from Xcode

- Step 1: `command` + click to `arc4random()`
- Step 2: Look at navigation bar

[image]

- Step 3: Right click on `stdlib.h`

[image]

- Step 4: Click on `include` folder and you will see what you want.

[image]

Comment: Okay, so here it is just function declaration. We cannot see the definition - where is it? In another file that is compiled?

Comment: @WojciechKazior Yes, it's in another file. I think it may be a `.cc` or `.ccp` file. But we can't open it from Xcode `command` + click ;)

Comment: Okay, I see... Is there another possibility to find and open it?

Comment: Yes, you can check everything here https://opensource.apple.com. For example, with `arc4random ()`, this is implemented file https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c

Comment: Hopefully that is the exact source that is used in arc4random() implementation. Thanks!

Comment: Still - I would be happy to find the .cpp file or something that is used by Xcode on my disk...

Comment: Welcome ;) . That's the exact source which Apple uses. Will be very grateful if my answer is marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @WojciechKazior One more thing for you to be assured, https://opensource.apple.com is provided by Apple ;)

Comment: I gave you +1 for an answer but cannot approve it yet, because I am still no sure why I cannot enter the implementation on my computer :)

Comment: @WojciechKazior After research, I think `build-in implementation file` is built to binary code and that's why we can't enter. They may be contained by `.bundle` or `.framework` file. If we can open implementation file, we still can't read code inside. Because it's binary code. Build implementation files to binary code may reduce time which is needed to build a project. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't access this specific implementation because it is Operating System's specific. But I think it's pretty likely that it's the same as [BSD's implementation](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/8443fee657f887e5c703cf81112924a3ea8476af/contrib/unbound/compat/arc4random.c), since the Apple documentation [describes](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) it as *"BSD Library Functions"*.

**Edit**: Being more specific, this function is part of the C standard library, and it's common practice to simply link it with the binary version distributed as part of the OS. So only the headers are normally available. Apple makes their libc source code available in the http://opensource.apple.com site though.

More broadly speaking though, you won't find the implementation of most Apple-related frameworks, except maybe `Foundation`, which is currently open source, and the Swift standard library.

Comment: So we still don't know if the implementation is Operating System's specific or exactly the same as in that link... But thanks anyway :)

Comment: As @trungduc pointed above, opensource.apple.com seems to be the official source of the library, so the source he linked seems to be the correct one.

Comment: @WojciechKazior In *theory* there's a way to know if a provided binary is the same implementation of a specific source, but I suppose it's very hard: you could compile yourself the source provided by Apple and check if the binaries match. But to have the same output, you'd have to use the exact same compiler flags that were used. So I'm not sure how much work that would be.

Answer (score 1):

you can't check implementation because it is defined in `stdlib.h` and you don't have its implementation file access.

Comment: I don't have access or the 'stdlib.h' is compiled?

Comment: Actually, you can open `stdlib.h`

Comment: @trungduc Yes, I can open it but there is only declaration of the function - not definition.

Comment: @WojciechKazior Yes, this is the deepest part you can see. I have added an answer. You can take a look if you want